# Help understanding the rules behind dividing by the largest power in the denominator of a limit to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was doing this problem and the rules for dividing by the largest power in the denominator of:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} n( \sqrt{n^{2}+4} - \sqrt{n^{2}-4} )$

I did the conjugate rule:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} n( \sqrt{n^{2}+4} - \sqrt{n^{2}-4} ) * \frac{ n(\sqrt{n^{2}+4} + \sqrt{n^{2}-4}) } {n(\sqrt{n^{2}-4} + \sqrt{n^{2}-4})}$

Simplified:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{8n}{ \sqrt{n^{2} + 4} + \sqrt{n^{2} - 4} }$

Now I know we must divide by the largest exponent in the denominator.
What are the rules for this when we have this set up with square-roots?

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Look at the denominator - how fast do you think it grows?  Divide by the power that seems right to you and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

$$n^2+a^2=n^2\left(1+\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^2\right)$$
so that
$$\sqrt{n^2+a^2}=\left|n\right|\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^2}$$
Apply for $a=\pm2$.